# how to construct a function to detect if a relation is active or expired - eloquent

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.1

I have two models: `Entity` and `Entityrelation`.
The Entities can enter relationships.
I try to construct a table with lists of present and past relations

in the `Entity` I have this function:

```
// Entity.php
public function activeMembership()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Entityrelation', 'entitychild_id')->NotCeased()->Where('relationtype_id', '=', '4');
}
```

The `NotCeased` is a scope defined in the `Entityrelation` model:

```
// Entityrelation.php
public function scopeCeased($query)
{
    return $query->where('ceased', 1);
}
public function scopeNotCeased($query)
{
    return $query->where('ceased', 0);
}
```

The `ceased` is a column in the relationships table.

So when I want to get a number of active memberships, I just do this :

```
$object = Entity::find(1);
```

and in my view

```
$object->public function activeMembership()->count();
```

and a simple `@foreach` loop produces me a list of all active memberships of the Entity with `id` = 1.

### My question

I want to design a function, which check if a given `Entity` was a child in an relation with an organization with ID = $parent_id (in `entityparent_id`).

- returns `1` when an active relationship was found.
- returns `0`when the found relation was expired (`ceased` = 1)
- returns `null` when no relation with the organization ever existed

Answer (score 0):

First off, your relationship is not properly defined. You should have this in Entity.php: ([relevant doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one))

```
public function entityRelation() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Entityrelation', 'entitychild_id');
}
```

Once you have this, you can use `$entity->entityRelation` to access an entity's relation.

Once you have that, it's pretty easy to do the requested function:

```
public function myMethod(Entity $entity, $parent_id) {
    if ($entity->entityRelation && $entity->entityRelation->id === $parent_id) {
        return $entity->entityRelation->ceased ? 0 : 1;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx. Today I am too busy to test yyour answer, please allow 24hsr for my feedback. Peter